# Can I use IEnumerable<> inside a View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

**In _Layout.cshtml**

```
    @model DynaPortalMVC.Models.Page
@using System.Linq
<ul>
     @IEnumerable<model.Page> pages = model.Where(x=>x.CompanyID == 1);
     @foreach (var item in pages)
     {
       <li>item.Title</li>
     }
 </ul>
```

In view iam trying to filter the model object called 'page' and get a list of pages whose id is 1. I need to iterate through this to show the menu.

Code inside Controller

```
public ActionResult Menu(string PageName)
    {
        //
        return View(PageName, db.Pages);
    }
```

Please tell me, how to filter out this model object to a list? I get errors on using IEnumerable.

**Solved**

I changed the model object to IEnumerable in view page.

```
@model IEnumerable<DynaPortalMVC.Models.Page>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can skip assigning the result of your query into an IEnumerable variable unless you will use it somewhere else on the page. So you can just do this:

```
@model DynaPortalMVC.Models.Page
@using System.Linq
<ul>
     @foreach (var item in model.Where(x=>x.CompanyID == 1))
     {
       <li>@item.Title</li>
     }
 </ul>
```

Comment: I tried to use this way , but my model is not a collection object, so i cant use 'where' condition directly on this.

Comment: I thought your object is a collection object because you asked on how to filter it. You should show us your code in your controller. But basically you should return a list of page objects from your controller. Even better is to return a **filtered** list so you don't put the filtering logic on your view.

Comment: Thanks, but is there any way to list or filter the model object which is not a collection? Because that is my requirement.

Comment: This breaks MVC's separation of concerns. Why can't you filter the data in the Controller and only send the View the data that is relevant?

Comment: To filter an object that is not a collection? Maybe the person who told you to do that means something else because that doesn't make sense.

Comment: If it's not a collection, enumerable or list of some sort; then how do you expect to filter or perform any collection based extensions on it... What is the nature of the model? At the moment; this is not a real question

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
@ {IEnumerable<model.Page> pages = Model.Where(x=>x.CompanyID == 1);}
```

Comment: Thanks for the correct syntax, this solved the error in using IEnumerable. But my model is not a collection object, so i cant use 'where' condition directly on that.

Answer (score 0):

```
@model IEnumerable<DynaPortalMVC.Models.Page>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Page";

}
```